# If in_array on multidimensional array and put value into first array

Tags: php

I have multidimensional array , I just want to push the matched value into another array: Can someone guide me to get the right array as I put into last line.

```
$getcount= Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => Array
                (
                    'pickup_trip_location' => 'Bishan',
                    'trip_route_id' => '1',
                    'c' => '5'
                ),

            1 => Array
                (
                    'pickup_trip_location' => 'Bukit Merah',
                    'trip_route_id' => 1,
                    'c' => 4
                ),

            2 => Array
                (
                    'pickup_trip_location' => 'Geylang',
                    'trip_route_id' => '1',
                    'c' => '2'
                ),

            3 => Array
                (
                    'pickup_trip_location' => 'Kallang',
                    'trip_route_id' => '1',
                    'c' => '3',
                ),

        )  ,

    1 => Array
        (
            0 => Array
                (
                    'pickup_trip_location' => 'Mandai',
                    'trip_route_id' => '2',
                    'c' => '2',
                ),
            1 => Array
                (
                    'pickup_trip_location' => 'Queenstown',
                    'trip_route_id' => '2',
                    'c' => '3',
                ),
            2 => Array
                (
                    'pickup_trip_location' => 'Toa Payoh',
                    'trip_route_id' => '2',
                    'c' => '1'
                ),
        )

);
```

second array:

```
$array1_1 =   Array
(
    0 => array
        (
            'stoppage_points' => 'Bishan,Bukit Merah,Geylang,Kallang,Toa Payoh,Ang Mo Kio',

        ),

    1 => array
        (
          
            'stoppage_points' => 'Queenstown,Toa Payoh,Bedok,Paya Lebar,Mandai,Changi,Yishun',
        )

);
```

```
$array = [];
//$String = "Bishan,Bukit Merah,Geylang,Kallang,Toa Payoh,Ang Mo Kio";
$f = 0 ;
foreach($array1_1 as $key_1 => $arr){
    $one=explode(",",$arr['stoppage_points']);

    $i = 0 ;
    foreach ($one as $key2=> $item){
        $array[$key_1][$key2] = explode(",",$item);
        $i++;
    }

    pr($array);
//die();

    foreach($getcount as $key_1 => $arr){
        //echo $key_1;
        $p = 0 ;
        foreach($arr as $key => $arr_1){
            echo $key;
            $arrayval = $arr_1['pickup_trip_location'];
            $c = $arr_1['c'];
            $trip_route_id = $arr_1['trip_route_id'];
            //echo $id =array_search($arrayval, $array[$key_1][$key][$p]);
            if( array_search( $arrayval ,$array[$key_1][$key]) ) {
                $array[$key]['pickup_trip_location'] = $arrayval;    
                $array[$key]['trip_route_id'] = $trip_route_id;    
                $array[$key]['count'] = $c;    
            }
        }
        $p++;
    }
    pr($array);
    $f++;
}
```

I want to output like this :  Getting output for first array only :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bishan
            [pickup_trip_location] => Bishan
            [trip_route_id] => 1
            [count] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bukit Merah
            [pickup_trip_location] => Bukit Merah
            [trip_route_id] => 1
            [count] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Geylang
            [pickup_trip_location] => Geylang
            [trip_route_id] => 1
            [count] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kallang
            [pickup_trip_location] => Kallang
            [trip_route_id] => 1
            [count] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Toa Payoh
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ang Mo Kio
        )

)
```

I have tried to push value into first array but didn't get any luck

Comment: Its amazing how much easier code is to read when it is properly layed out and indented [Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.